# Oracle SQL Most-Often SELECT Query

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(customerID     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
customerFirName     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerLasName     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerMiName      VARCHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
customerStreet      VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
customerState       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
customerCity        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerZip     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN     VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
vehicleType     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleType) IN ('compact', 'midsize', 'fullsize', 'suv', 'truck')),
vehicleMake     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
vehicleModel        VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
vehicleWhereFrom    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleWhereFrom) IN ('maryland','virginia','washington, d.c.')),
vehicleWholesaleCost    DECIMAL(9,2)    NOT NULL,
vehicleTradeID      INT);

CREATE TABLE SALES
(saleID         INT     PRIMARY KEY,
grossSalePrice      DECIMAL(9,2),
vehicleStatus       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleStatus) IN ('available', 'sold', 'pending')),
saleDate        DATE,
saleMileage     INT,
customerID      INT,
salespersonID       INT,
vehicleVIN      VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(customerID),
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (vehicleVIN) REFERENCES VEHICLES(vehicleVIN);
```

I am trying to pull a query that shows the vehicleMake that was involved in the most sales and all of the customers that purchased a vehicle of that make, but I'm coming up short. I think my logic is off somewhere, but I can't seem to pin down the issue. Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.VEHICLEMAKE, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VEHICLEVIN) "SALES_BY_MAKE", c.CUSTOMERFULLNAME, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CUSTOMERZIP)"CUSTOMERS"
FROM SALES s, VEHICLES v, CUSTOMERS c
WHERE s. VEHICLEVIN = v. VEHICLEVIN
and c. CUSTOMERID = s. CUSTOMERID
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

And here's the output I get:

```
VEHICLEMAKE     SALES_BY_MAKE CUSTOMERFULLNAME  CUSTOMERS

Chevrolet                  11 Adam E Whitney           2
Chevrolet                  11 Alberto L Ross           2
Chevrolet                  11 Alexis T Moon            2
Chevrolet                  11 Finley H Tritt           2
Chevrolet                  11 Jayda V Rush             2
Chevrolet                  11 Junior E Hanes           2
Chevrolet                  11 Kamari H Webster         1
Chevrolet                  11 Linda L Lawrence         2
Chevrolet                  11 Luke E Boyer             4
Chevrolet                  11 Samantha D Holden        2
Chevrolet                  11 Sydnee B Herman          2
```

I need the output to look like the following:

```
VEHICLEMAKE     SALES_BY_MAKE CUSTOMERFULLNAME

Chevrolet                  11 Adam E Whitney           
                              Alberto L Ross           
                              Alexis T Moon            
                              Finley H Tritt           
                              Jayda V Rush             
                              Junior E Hanes           
                              Kamari H Webster         
                              Linda L Lawrence         
                              Luke E Boyer             
                              Samantha D Holden        
                              Sydnee B Herman
```

As shown, the CUSTOMERS column isn't needed, but when I remove it, I get an error. Maybe I'm going about the approach all wrong with DISTINCT?

Basically, I just need a SINGLE SELECT QUERY that shows the Make of the vehicle listed once, the number of sales listed once, and then the list of the customers purchasing a vehicle of that make. It should also account for the possibility of two or more vehicles holding the top number of sales, for instance if both Chevrolet and Ford had 11 sales, they should both appear on the list, along with the customers names who purchased them.

I hope I haven't made this too confusing. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; this works well.

```
WITH
vehicleMakeCount AS
(
    SELECT
        SALES.saleID, SALES.customerID, SALES.vehicleVIN, VEHICLES.vehicleMake,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY VEHICLES.vehicleMake) AS salesByMake
    FROM
        SALES
        INNER JOIN
            VEHICLES ON VEHICLES.vehicleVIN  = SALES.vehicleVIN
),
salesRank AS
(
    SELECT
        vehicleMakeCount.*,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salesByMake DESC)   AS vehicleMakeSalesRank
    FROM
        vehicleMakeCount
)
SELECT CUSTOMERS.customerFullName, salesRank.vehicleMake
FROM
salesRank
    INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMERS
    ON CUSTOMERS.customerID = salesRank.customerID
    WHERE
    salesRank.vehicleMakeSalesRank = 1
    ORDER BY salesRank.vehicleMake;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT vc.*
FROM (SELECT vc.*, MAX(SALES_BY_MAKE) OVER () as MAX_SALES_BY_MAKE
      FROM (SELECT v.VEHICLEMAKE, c.CUSTOMERFULLNAME,
                   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VEHICLEMAKE) as SALES_BY_MAKE
            FROM SALES s JOIN
                 VEHICLES v
                 ON s.VEHICLEVIN = v.VEHICLEVIN JOIN
                 CUSTOMERS c
                 ON c.CUSTOMERID = s.CUSTOMERID 
           ) vc
     ) vc
WHERE SALES_BY_MAKE = MAX_SALES_BY_MAKE
ORDER BY VEHICLEMAKE;
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add that it is supposed to be completed via a single SELECT query. I'm assuming that although this has multiple SELECT statements, since it is contained within one query (SELECT vc.*) it will still only be one SELECT Query? My apologies, I'm still very novice at this and trying to learn all of the ins and outs as I go along.

Comment: So, this actually is not working. Just popped it into my program and it returns the error ORA-00907 for missing right parenthesis on line 7 (ON s.VEHICLEVIN=v VEHICLEVIN JOIN). Tried adding parentheses and then it doesn't like the following lines. Are you sure this will work with Oracle? Thanks.

Comment: @StevenC . . . That was a small typo, missing a `.`.

Comment: Hmm...Ok, now it executes without error, although it doesn't display the proper output. It lists each "VEHICLEMAKE" repetitively, so the sales by make is only 1... For example, the VEHICLEMAKE column has ashton martin listed 4 times, and the sales by make is only 1 for each listing. Even though the max sales by make shout be 4 since 4 ashton martin's were sold. Does that explain it clearly? If not, I can update the OP with the output so you can see it better? Thanks!

Comment: @StevenC . . . I wonder if I misread the original question.  In any case, the innermost subquery should clearly be partitioning by vehicle make rather than vehicle id.

Comment: Hmm. So I'm still lost here. How do I get it to combine the counts for the sales by make? For example, right now, it lists each make individually as 1 sale, versus listing the make once and showing 4, 5, etc. sales.

Answer (score 0):

If it was SQL*Plus, you could have used its `BREAK` command to produce such an effect. Nowadays people rarely use it, but who knows - you (or someone else) might need it. I hope you won't mind me posting it.

```
SQL> break on job_id on cnt
SQL>
SQL> select job_id,
  2    count(*) over (partition by job_id) cnt,
  3    last_name
  4  From employees
  5  where job_id between 'AD_VP' and 'MK_MAN'
  6  order by job_id, last_name;

JOB_ID            CNT LAST_NAME
---------- ---------- -------------------------
AD_VP               2 De Haan
                      Kochhar
FI_ACCOUNT          5 Chen
                      Faviet
                      Popp
                      Sciarra
                      Urman
FI_MGR              1 Greenberg
HR_REP              1 Mavris
IT_PROG             5 Austin
                      Ernst
                      Hunold
                      Lorentz
                      Pataballa
MK_MAN              1 Hartstein

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```